# Conditionally execute scanf function?

Tags: c

So I have a program where I need to take an initial command from a user using the scanf function, the problem is it could just be one string command, one string command and a string argument, one string command and a int argument or one string command and two int arguments

so I need to somehow create one scanf function that is able to handle all of these because I don't know which one will be picked first

so the code I made to handle all edge cases is

```
scanf("%s", c);
scanf("%s%s", c, s;
scanf("%s%d", c, &i);
scanf("%s%d%d", c, &i, &i2);
```

and examples of possible commands that could be typed by end user

```
 print
 insert Hello
 del 4 
 pick 2 5
```

but this won't work

So is there a way to make a scanf function that executes conditionally?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could read only the first word and then determine what you need to read next :

```
char command[32];
scanf("%s", command);
if(strncmp(command, "print", 32) == 0) {
    ...
}
else if(strncmp(command, "insert", 32) == 0) {
    char string[32];
    scanf("%s", string);
    ...
}
else if(strncmp(command, "del", 32) == 0) {
    int i;
    scanf("%d", &i);
    ...
}
else if(strncmp(command, "pick", 32) == 0) {
    int i, j;
    scanf("%d %d", &i, &j);
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Read the whole line, preferably with a safe function like fgets, then parse the resulting string to determine if the user wrote a valid command. Conditional execution can then be achieved using the `if` statement.

Answer (score 2):

since scanf family of functions returns the number of successfully parsed fields, get the complete string using gets, then use sscanf placing the longer patterns before:

```
char buffer[,..], cmd[...];
int num1, num2;

gets(buffer);
if (sscanf(buffer, "%[^ ] %d %d", cmd, &num1, &num2) == 3) {
...
}
else if (sscanf(buffer, "%[^ ] %d", cmd, &num1) == 2) {
...
} else {
...
}
```

the pattern `%[^ ]` get a string excluded the first blank.
Also, separating patterns by space, scanf skip *any* whitespace between...

Answer (score 1):

Read whole line, then use `sscanf` to parse it.

Some bad code follows:

```
scanf("%s", buf);
if (strcmp(buf, "print") == 0) {
    call_print();
} else if (strncmp(buf, "insert ", 7) == 0) {
    call_insert(buf + 7); // pointer magic!
} else if (strncmp(buf, "del ", 4) == 0) {
    int i;
    sscanf(buf + 4, "%d", &i); // feel free to use atoi or something
    call_del(i);
} else if (strncmp(buf, "pick ", 5) == 0) {
    int i, i2;
    sscanf(buf + 5, "%d%d", &i, &i2);
    call_pick(i, i2);
} else {
    printf("Does not compute!\n");
}
```